# Should all grid contents be divisible by 8 or an even number?

Tags: material-design, grid

When designing a grid system it is advisable to use an 8pt grid. This is stated by Material Design and many others. Does this mean that columns and gutters all must be divisible by 8 or a smaller even number such as 4 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

No. Not because of material design but its founder angular therefore google made [**their theme**](https://material.angular.io) that way. If you look at **`Spacing`** section under [**Material UI Grid component on React**](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing), it states that;

> The responsive grid focuses on consistent spacing widths, rather than
>   column width. Material Design margins and columns follow an 8px square
>   baseline grid. The spacing property is an integer between 0 and 10
>   inclusive. By default, the spacing between two grid items follows a
>   linear function: output(spacing) = spacing * 8px, e.g. spacing={2}
>   creates a 16px wide gap.

That way which points out the spacing between grid items ought to be folds of 8px and that doesn't mean you have to divide your overall page to 8, 4 or 2. Instead, you may use the rest of the grid space however you prefer to apply.

You'll realize the grids displayed with 12pt, 6, 3, etc. like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) does in general.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. On the react link you provided they are all multiples of 8.

Comment: Hey @larryburns, if you take a look at the [**Spacing section**](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing) of the page above, it states that **`The responsive grid focuses on consistent spacing widths, rather than column width. Material Design margins and columns follow an 8px square baseline grid. The spacing property is an integer between 0 and 10 inclusive. By default, the spacing between two grid items follows a linear function: output(spacing) = spacing * 8px, e.g. spacing={2} creates a 16px wide gap`** that doesn't mean you have to divide your overall page to 8, 4 or 2.

Comment: this was the result of coding conveniences considerations trumping all others. Do as you wish. Prefer an odd number, when you need a middle where you can place things within a cel, etc. Guidelines are merely guidelines.

Comment: Hello again @larryburns, would you please take a look at my answer again and check out the pointed out links as if necessary re-reading them. Because I think you're misunderstood with close terms used for relatively different purposes.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar so does this mean you can use say an 11px column width and 5px gutter because it adds up to 16px? I don't see how you can follow an 8px square baseline grid without using even numbers.

Comment: @Confused amazing username lol. I still don't understand how you can follow an 8px baseline grid with odd numbers.

Comment: I think you don't need to understand everything in the world and all the technological background once. So that's pretty enough for my part to explain further since you probably don't understand either I do explain . Basically the answer is no though.